# How does the switch statement work? The case labels are variables, and the expression passed in is a number

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript through a book on HTML5 games, and I've come to some code that I can't really wrap my head around. It's a 2D array that generates a game map.

What I can't figure out is how the switch statement knows to use the WATER, ISLAND, PIRATE, HOME variables when the expression passed in is a number. How does it know that that 0 means WATER instead of just treating it like a normal 0 that doesn't have a case label?

```
var map = [
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

var WATER = 0;
var ISLAND = 1;
var PIRATE = 2;
var HOME = 3;

var ROWS = map.length;
var COLUMNS = map[0].length;

function render() {

for(var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {   
  for(var column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++) { 
    var cell = document.createElement("img");
    cell.setAttribute("class", "cell");
    stage.appendChild(cell);

  switch(map[row][column]) {
    case WATER:
      cell.src = "../images/water.png";
      break;

    case ISLAND:
      cell.src = "../images/island.png";
      break; 

    case PIRATE:
      cell.src = "../images/pirate.png";
      break; 

    case HOME:
      cell.src = "../images/home.png";
      break;   
  } 
    }
  }
}
```

Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's the other way round. `WATER` is a constant that means `0`, and only this value is what the `switch` statement cares about.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. Sorry I can only accept one. I guess was getting confused because somehow I didn't realize that the case clauses were the same global variables defined earlier. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), you can see that each `case` clause accepts an **expression** which is evaluated and compared against the value passed to `switch`:

> The program first looks for a `case` clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the input expression (using strict comparison, `===`) and then transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements.

So when `0` is passed as value to `switch`, `case WATER:` is evaluated and since the variable `WATER` evaluates to `0` (its value), the case matches.

Answer (score 0):

Under the 2D array 4 variableshave been declared

```
var WATER = 0;
var ISLAND = 1;
var PIRATE = 2;
var HOME = 3;
```

in the switch statement the variables are then used. So even though it reads case WATER, WATER is a variable who's value is 0. So when 0 is passed in it will match this case.

Answer (score 0):

These vars are effectively enumerations that stand for the value listed --

```
var WATER = 0;
var ISLAND = 1;
var PIRATE = 2;
var HOME = 3;
```

So in the switch statement 
witch(map[row][column]) {
    case WATER:
      cell.src = "../images/water.png";
      break;

WATER's value is 0, so this statement is effectively case 0:

Answer (score 0):

Well Javascript knows because you've set `var WATER = 0;`. So what the switch statement is doing is taking the map[row][column] and evaluating it against WATER (which equals 0). If the two match then it goes into the nested statement, otherwise it keeps going down the list looking for a match.